# How to install Windows 8 on an early 2006 MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, startup

I have recently obtained a MacBook 1,1 from my older sister and it happens to be quite old. I have attempted to revive it with boot camp but my windows installation is stored on a USB drive instead of a DVD, and Boot Camp refuses to use it. I have OS X 10.5 Leopard installed. Also, I tried to burn a Windows xp disk, but Boot Camp wouldn't accept that either. Any help would be appreciated.

Info:
Nice Name: MacBook 13 inch White Core Duo (Mid 2006)
Machine Model: MacBook1,1
Name: MacBook (early 2006)
ModelCode: mb
Family name: A1181
Model Number: MA255
Group1: MacBook
Group2: nothing
Generation: 1
CPU speed: 2.0GHz
Screen size: 13 inch
Screen resolution: 1280x800 pixels
Colour: White
Production year: 2006
Production week: 39 (October)
Production number: 350 (within this week)
Model introduced: 2006
Memory - flavour: DDR2-S-667
Memory - number of slots: 2
Memory - maximum total: 2GB
Memory - largest module: 1GB
Factory: 4H (China)

Comment: did you check if that model accepts those ?

Comment: I know for sure it accepts windows XP SP2 and Vista x86 and the windows disk I burnt was SP2. Also, I'm hoping to find a way to do this manually, without boot camp. Is there something that would prevent Windows 8 from being installed? I mean it's x86, needs only about 512 MB of RAM and I could obtain the apple drivers from the internet afterwards, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 needs Boot Camp 5.1

Your Macbook can only run Boot Camp from DVD, not from USB [same for any Superdrive-euipped Macbook] & also can, as far as I can tell, only run Boot Camp 4.
That means your only choices are Windows XP or Vista, 32-bit.

See [Boot Camp: System requirements for Microsoft Windows operating systems](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204048)

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootcamp to install. This will enable you to choose what OS should be loaded when you power on the macbook.

Another solution is to use a virtual machine. Products that are used the most (in my opinion) are vmware and parallels dekstop.

My advice to you is to use bootcamp since you have an older macbook. When running a virtual machine in OS X will probable decrease your performance drastically.

I also recommend not to use the latest version of windows. This will probable also to heavy for your macbook.

When you want to have better performance, you could consider upgrading your random access memory (RAM).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to install the windows version that your mac accepts at first then once installed you can upgrade to Windows 8 from there.